# How to dynamically create multiple database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am creating Laravel 6.6 project,
my query is how to create new multiple databases in laravel and then how to handle it,

if I fetch data from the new database that I was recently created then how to register a new database in **.env** file dynamically?

Comment: On the surface this sounds like a bad idea. Can you explain for what reason you think you need many databases

Comment: If you have multiple `database`, you can changes connection dynamically using `database.php` file, not sure whether you can dynamically changes `.env`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am Creating Inventory Management system, the client has so many branches so every branch has a different database, that reason I am creating dynamic database creation, do  you have any idea for manage different branch records

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this the following way.

I do have a dummy entry for my client connections in my `config/database.php` like this:

```
        'clientDb' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_CLIENT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_CLIENT_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_CLIENT_DATABASE', 'some_default_client_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_CLIENT_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_CLIENT_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_CLIENT_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'dump' => [],
        ],
```

So, all my client-related models are used with `$connection = 'clientDb';`, the others using the default connection.

When changing a client (so i need to switch the connection), i just set the new connection by calling:

```
Config::set('database.connections.clientDb', [
   'database' => NEW_DATABASE_NAME,
   // all the other params from config
]);
```

After that, i figured out to call `DB::reconnect('clientDb');` to get the connection *really* running.

I hope, this will lead you to the right direction

Comment: thank you for replying but my query is how to creating database and manege using the only frontend, no backend interaction is there

Comment: ...and you say `laravel` and `no backend interaction`...this bites each other ... you do have laravel installed and use it? Please clearify your question a bit more, so we can help...

Comment: sorry for that, I am creating on a system, on this many branches added after deployment, so I have provided functionality that user can add branches on the frontend, and every branch have a different database, main question is to how to manage newly added database in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You should usage from database.php in config directory. for example I have another mysql database which is different from main db:
so I add this code to database.php and connections section:

```
 'mysql_second_db' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND_DB', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND_DB', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND_DB', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND_DB', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND_DB', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Comment: thank you for replying but my query is how to creating database and manege using the only frontend, no backend interaction is there

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
 $names=['name1','name2'];
  Schema::create('t1', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
    });
```

To set env look at that: [ENV](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Comment: -Patryk thank you for replying but I have different query